# WFS-T call to Geoserver not visualising POIs

Tags: dictionary, edit, openlayers, openstreetmap, geoserver

I'd like to make a connection to Geoserver to edit several point of a layer via WFS-T. I tried this starting by different examples but the map doesn't visualise the points. I have an openstreetmap base layer exposed via WMS. The server logs the call with the points I asked for...
Here is the call I'm making:

```
var wfs_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Editable Features", {
                 strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(), saveStrategy],
                 protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
                           url: "http://192.168.0.10:8080/geoserver/wfs",
                           params: {
                                   service: "WFS",
                                   version: "1.0.0",
                                   srsName: "EPSG:3004",
                                   request: "GetFeature",
                                   typeName: "Incendi:inc2008",
                                   outputFormat: "gml3"
                           },
                  filterToParams: function(filter, params) {
                    // example to demonstrate BBOX serialization
                    if (filter.type === OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX) {
                        params.bbox = filter.value.toArray();
                        if (filter.projection) {
                            params.bbox.push(filter.projection.getCode());
                        }
                    }
                    return params;
                 }
                 })
 });
```

Thanks in advance for your replies

Comment: Are you debugging to see if you're actually getting a set of params?

Comment: Now the problem is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292911/proxying-apache-with-8081-port-to-geoserver-8080-for-wfs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caused by limitation on cross-origin javascript. I need to use a host to enable WFSs call from a remote server.