# Proxying Apache with 8081 port to Geoserver 8080 for WFS

Tags: apache, tomcat, proxy, openlayers, geoserver

I've been in a dilemma for several days and now I'd really appreciate your help.
Here is my situation:
- Ubuntu Linux (All ports opened)
- Apache running on port 8081
- Geoserver Tomcat on port 8080
I'm trying to make a WFS connection by a different pc than the server so I need to use a proxy.
In my server I edited httpd.conf and added these lines:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ProxyPass /geoserver http://mydomain.com:8080/geoserver
ProxyPassReverse /geoserver http://mydomain.com:8080/geoserver
```

I downloaded proxy.cgi from OpenLayers and edited to add my allowed hosts (localhost:8081, localhost, mydomain:8081, etc.)
When I open proxy.cgi in the web browser I'm forwarded to the openlayers site, so I think that python and the script are running correctly.
Then I added http://mydomain.com:8081/geoserver to the base proxy URL in geoserver dashboard.
In my html I point every script file like Openlayers.js, GeoExt,js to apache so with port 8081.
Inside my init function I put:

```
OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
```

and the vector layer with WFS is like this:

```
var inc2007 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Inc", {
                                          styleMap: styles1,
       strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
         protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
             url: "http://mydomain.com:8081/geoserver/wfs",
                                                  featurePrexif: "Inc",
                                                  featureType: "Inc",
             featureNS: "http://mydomain.com:8080/Incendi"

                                        }),
    });
```

I can't see this layer on the map and firebug doesn't log anything.
I tried to change the ProxyHost link to "http://mydomain.com:8081/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=" but nothing.
What can I do?
I really...really need your help.

Thanks in advance for your replies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by putting proxy.cgi on the local apache and not on the apache residing on the geoserver machine...

Comment: Answered a similar [question here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20328/path-to-proxy-cgi-for-geoserver-is-not-accessible-in-browser/20376#20376)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure all the openlayers WFS protocol properties match up correctly to their corresponding GeoServer properties.

nine times out of ten, this is why the WFS layer does not show up.

Take a look at my answers [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/19033/how-to-add-a-simple-wfs-layer-from-geoserver-to-openlayers-map/19041#19041) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12144/openlayers-wfs-vector-layer/12151#12151).

Comment: The same vector works on the geoserver machine. I tried to change up the Strategy to Fixed but the result is the same.

Comment: Have you made sure you're geoserver properties match? Your geoserver `workspace name` and `layer name` are both named "Inc"? Your Geoserver  Workspace Namespace URI is set to `http://mydomain.com:8080/Incendi`?

Comment: Yes indeed. They are as you said.